# Error al guardar ciertos archivos en python con pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intentando descargar música con pytube, este es mi archivo con el que descargo los videos en formato `mp4` y despues los convierto a `mp3`:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import sys
import os

url = sys.argv[1]

def download_video_audio(video):
    video = YouTube(url)
    video = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
    old_name  = video.download(output_path='/var/www/html/videos', filename="{}.mp4".format(video.title))
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(old_name)
    new_file = base + '.mp3'
    os.rename(base + '.mp4', new_file)

    return video.title

title = download_video_audio(url)
print(title)
```

Hasta ahí todo va bien, por ejemplo si yo ejecuto este archivo de esta forma `archivo.py 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Qp5vcuMIlk'`, si me descarga el archivo y me muestra el título de la canción, el cuál es el resultado esperado, pero si en cambio (voy a poner de ejemplo un video con el cual da error), si yo ejecuto ese mismo archivo pero de esta forma `archivo.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SC0Ze4ta9o` me da este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 17, in <module>
    title = download_video_audio(url)
  File "download.py", line 10, in download_video_audio
    old_name  = video.download(output_path='/var/www/html/videos', filename="{}.mp4".format(video.title))
  File "/home/davebook/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/streams.py", line 250, in download
    with open(file_path, "wb") as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/html/videos/Yo Contigo, Tú Conmigo (The Gong Gong Song / El Tema De La Película "Gru 3 Mi Villano F....mp4'
```

Realmente no se porque puede ocurrir este error, ya que solo pasa con ciertos videos, espero puedan ayudarme a solucionarlo. Desde ya gracias :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es por el nombre del video de Youtube.
Los archivos y directorios no deben contener caracteres o nombres ilegales como: <>:"/|*?

Una solución es reemplazar los caracteres ilegales del nombre del video, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```py
import re

# Reemplazas con un - los caracteres ilegales del nombre
title= re.sub(r'[<>:"/\|*?]', "-" , video.title) 

old_name= video.download(output_path='/var/www/html/videos', filename=f"{title}.mp4")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :).

Comment: O sin usar re, `simbols = '<>:"/\|*?'
translator = str.maketrans(simbols, "-"*len(simbols))

title = r"Las <Cronicas> de /\: una mala pelicula?"

title = title.translate(translator)`. Nota: esto solo sirve si se quiere cambiar un caracter por otro. No sirve para eliminarlos, en ese caso es mejor usar regex.